# Why the items are not shrinked automatically when we have flex-direction: column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
.box-1 {
  background: #e51400;
}
.box-2 {
  background: #fa6800;
}
.box-3 {
  background: #f0a30a; 
}
.box-4 {background: #e3c800; }
.box-5 {background: #a4c400;}
.box-6 {background: #60a917;}
.box-7 {background: #00aba9;}
.box-8 {background: #1ba1e2;} 
.box-9 {background: #aa00ff;}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 8px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="box box-1">1</div>
        <div class="box box-2">2</div>
        <div class="box box-3">3</div>
        <div class="box box-4">4</div> 
        <div class="box box-5">5</div>
        <div class="box box-6">6</div>
        <div class="box box-7">7</div>
        <div class="box box-8">8</div>
        <div class="box box-9">9</div>  
</section>
```

When we have `flex-direction: row` (the default) and setted `width` on flex-items, they are shrinked in the parent itself so now they are not 300px wide, they try to shrnk to fit in the parent's width because of the `flex-shrink` property which has default value of 1 in the flexbox.

But when I change `flex-direction: row` to `flex-direction: column`
then flex items are going outside of the parent's `height`. Why is that ?

Comment: Could you add a working example?

Comment: you need `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` on the `display:flex` child elements (`.box`). Or use a shorthand like `flex: 1 1;`

Comment: @SecretTimes you can copy paste - you have the whole code. Because it is small code i did not provide stackblitz example

Comment: @teefars i don't understand what are you suggesting

Comment: @CalvinNunes i did not set line-height of my flex-items. And if i do, i am asking why it is not handled by flexbox automatically like he is doing when we have flex-direction:row ? There also when we set bigger width then the parent, the width is shrinked automatically by the flexbox it self

Comment: It seems you should read a [flexbox manual](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) before asking these questions. [Also, it doesn't matter if the code is short, if you want your question answered provide enough information so we can help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well, in short: When using `column` there is no enough space to fit the child inside `.container` and flexbox will not fix this by itself. You can reduce the line-height, set a max-height, reduce the font-size, or add flex-wrap: wrap to .container or add an overflow: hidden. When using `row`, the children adjust due to flex-shrink because there is enough space, add width 200px to .container and the children will overflow like in the `column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 9 `.box` elements having a height of 60px that are trying to fit in a `.container` of 500px height.

If you do the math : 9*60px = 540px, which is bigger than your `.container` height.

The content of your your `.box`es isn't shrinked because you did set a `font-size: 50px` and the total line-height makes it 60px. This is because [the CSS `line-height` property is by default at 110% or 120% depending on your browser](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/line-height.html)

In this case, the total height of your element is

```
font-size * line-height => 50px * 1.2 => 60px
```

This is not a free space in your `.box` that flexbox will be able to shrink to fit your boxes in your container.

As [teefars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270775/teefars) mentionned, I recommend you to [read a guide about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hello. Can you please tell me what you mean by - you have 9 .box elements that are having a height of 60px ? I don't have height:60px inside my .box css style selector. Please explain

Comment: @user17190872 The height of your element in your case is equal to your element `font-size` * `line-height` (which is 1.2 by default) => 50px * 1.2 = 60px

Comment: can you please provide link where this rule is written ? Because when i inspect the element height on my browser , it is not saying that is is 60px but 70px

Comment: @user17190872 The link is available in my answer :) Note that `line-height` is a CSS property and you may change it if you need. You can set it at 1 if you want your `.box` elements height to be equal to your `font-size`